# Print esri Map doesn't show feature layer

Tags: printing, feature-layer

I Have a map with some feature layer. I make a print function to print map to pdf and it run correctly.
But when i set filter to feature layer, the layer doesn't show on the pdf print. Please help for my problem.

This the sample code :

```
 app.flroad.setDefinitionExpression("Year=" + "'" + right(periode[0], 4) + "'" + " and month=" + "'" + left(periode[0], 2) + "'");
    app.flbound.setDefinitionExpression("Year=" + "'" + right(periode[1], 4) + "'" + " and month=" + "'" + left(periode[1], 2) + "'");
```